# Update column of Table B based on column of Table A

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a huge stored  procedure and I am trying to optimize it .

I have a temporary table **A** , with column **Id**.

I have a main table B with columns **Id** & a boolean field **Test**

For all Id's in Table A , I need to make the Test = 1 in Table B.

example :
**A**

```
Id
--
1
2
3
```

I need to get table B as follows.
I already have the Id field in Table B , I only need to update the 
Test Column
    **B**

```
Id Test
-- ----
1   1
2   1
3   1
4
5
6
```

I am currently looping through Table **A** using a while loop and for each Id
I am updating the Test column in Table **B** .

```
WHILE (1 = 1) 
BEGIN  

  -- Exit loop if no more Transactions
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;

  Update [B]
  set Test = 1 
  where Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id
  FROM #B
  WHERE Id > @Id1 
  ORDER BY Id)    

END
```

PS : @Id1 is the input parameter of the stored procedure.

I cannot think of any other efficient way of doing it, but 
my query is taking a lot of time to run..
Please let me know if there is a better way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop for this, just join those tables

```
UPDATE B
SET B.Test = 1
FROM TableB B
INNER JOIN TableA A
   ON A.Id = B.ID
```

[**Here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd127/1) with a live demo.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straight forward.

```
UPDATE [B] 
    SET [TEST] = 1 
FROM [B] INNER JOIN [A]
    ON [A].ID = [B].ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
UPDATE b SET test = 1
  FROM dbo.TableB AS b
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableA WHERE ID = b.ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` to find the records to update:

```
update b
set Test = 1
where Id in (select Id from #A)
```

Another alternative is to join the tables:

```
update x
set Test = 1
from b as x
inner join #A as a on a.id = x.id
```

Comment: Thank you for the Alternate Solutions  !

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you need to do is join A and B.

```
UPDATE TableB SET test = 1
FROM TableB b
INNER JOIN TableA a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.ID > @Id1
```

Basically you're looking to update everywhere where TableA and TableB intersect.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html